# Boolean variables in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, optional-arguments

I am trying to use "boolean" variables in LaTeX but am unable to have any success...

I have a macro which takes 5 arguments, the last argument being optional. This macro is named `educationItem` and it only ever appears in an `education` environment. So, some `educationItem` entries will have this fifth argument, and some will not. The ones that have the fifth argument will require a slightly modified formatting.

In addition, I would like the ability to disable this fifth argument for all `educationItem` entries, such that it appears as if all `educationItem` entries have no fifth argument. In order to do this, I am currently using an option passed when including my `cvtools.sty` file.

My current attempt (shown below) does not seem to work and stuffs up the table alignment. I think that it may be due to the time at which the various expressions are evaluated, but have not been able to fix it.

[image: Table misalignment]

Any help would be appreciated.

A minimum working example follows:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{cvtools} % my CV styling stuff
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}   % extend page margins

\begin{document}

\section*{Education}
\begin{education}

\educationItem{2008}{2012}
{Education 1}
{University 1}
{}

\educationItem{2002}{2007}
{Education 2}
{University 2}
{
\educationGrade{Subject 1}{90/100}
\educationGrade{Subject 2}{88/100}
\educationGrade{Subject 3}{97/100}
\educationGrade{Subject 4}{94/100}
\educationGrade{Subject 5}{95/100}
}
\end{education}

\end{document}
```

cvtools.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{cvtools}[2012/07/16 v1.0.0]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}           % for \ifstrempty, \ifdef
\RequirePackage{ifthen}             % for \ifthenelse
\RequirePackage{longtable}          % for tables that span more than one page
\RequirePackage{multirow}           % for table columns that span more than one row
\RequirePackage{tabularx}           % for simple column stretching
\RequirePackage{xcolor}             % for colours

%================================================%
% Declare options
%================================================%
\newif\if@showgrades

\DeclareOption{showgrades}{\@showgradestrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{cvtools}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}}

\ProcessOptions

%================================================%
% For table styling
%================================================%
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
%------------------------------------------------%

%================================================%
% \begin{education}
% \educationItem{beginYear}{endYear}{name}{institution}{\educationGrade{subject}{grade} ...}
% \end{education}
%================================================%
\newenvironment{education}%
{%
\def\lwidth{0.16\textwidth}%
\def\rwidth{0.78\textwidth}%
%
\newcommand\educationGrade[2]{##1 & ##2 \\}%
%
\newcommand\educationItem[5]{%
% Check if we should display tools
\if@showgrades
    \ifstrempty{##5}%
        {% showGrades is true, but this \educationItem has no grades to display.
            \def\@numRows{1}%
            \def\@shouldshowgrades{0}
        }%
        {% showGrades is true and this \educationItem has grades to display.
            \def\@numRows{2}%
            \def\@shouldshowgrades{1}
        }%
\else
    % showGrades is false.
    \def\@numRows{1}%
    \def\@shouldshowgrades{0}
\fi
%
% Education period
\multirow{\@numRows}{\lwidth}{##1 -- ##2}%
%
% Name and institution
& \textbf{##3 (##4)}%
%
% Grades
\ifthenelse{\equal{@shouldshowgrades}{1}}%
    {%
        \\* %
        & \begin{tabularx}{\rwidth}{Xr} %
        ##5 %
        \end{tabularx} %
    }%
    {}%
\\[0.5em]%
}%
%
\begin{longtable}{L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}%
}
{\end{longtable}}
%------------------------------------------------%
```

The expected output would be identical to the following TeX code... when using `\usepackage[showgrades]{cvtools}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}   % extend page margins
\RequirePackage{longtable}          % for tables that span more than one page
\RequirePackage{multirow}           % for table columns that span more than one row
\RequirePackage{tabularx}           % for simple column stretching
\RequirePackage{xcolor}             % for colours

%================================================%
% For table styling
%================================================%
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
%------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\section*{Education}
% \begin{education}
\def\lwidth{0.16\textwidth}
\def\rwidth{0.78\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}

% \educationItem{2008}{2012}
% {Education 1}
% {University 1}
% {}
\multirow{1}{\lwidth}{2008 -- 2012}
& \textbf{Education 1 (University 1)}%
% @shouldshowgrades should be false here
\\[0.5em]

% \educationItem{2002}{2007}
% {Education 2}
% {University 2}
% {
% ...
% }
\multirow{1}{\lwidth}{2002 -- 2007}
& \textbf{Education 2 (University 2)}%
% @shouldshowgrades should be true here
\\*
& \begin{tabularx}{\rwidth}{Xr} %
% \educationGrade{Subject 1}{90/100}
Subject 1 & 90/100 \\
% \educationGrade{Subject 2}{88/100}
Subject 2 & 88/100 \\
% \educationGrade{Subject 3}{97/100}
Subject 3 & 97/100 \\
% \educationGrade{Subject 4}{94/100}
Subject 4 & 94/100 \\
% \educationGrade{Subject 5}{95/100}
Subject 5 & 95/100 \\
\end{tabularx}
\\[0.5em]

% \end{education}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

When using `\usepackage{cvtools}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}   % extend page margins
\RequirePackage{longtable}          % for tables that span more than one page
\RequirePackage{multirow}           % for table columns that span more than one row
\RequirePackage{tabularx}           % for simple column stretching
\RequirePackage{xcolor}             % for colours

%================================================%
% For table styling
%================================================%
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{p{#1}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}
%------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\section*{Education}
% \begin{education}
\def\lwidth{0.16\textwidth}
\def\rwidth{0.78\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}

% \educationItem{2008}{2012}
% {Education 1}
% {University 1}
% {}
\multirow{1}{\lwidth}{2008 -- 2012}
& \textbf{Education 1 (University 1)}%
% @shouldshowgrades should be false here
\\[0.5em]

% \educationItem{2002}{2007}
% {Education 2}
% {University 2}
% {
% \educationGrade{Subject 1}{90/100}
% \educationGrade{Subject 2}{88/100}
% \educationGrade{Subject 3}{97/100}
% \educationGrade{Subject 4}{94/100}
% \educationGrade{Subject 5}{95/100}
% }
\multirow{1}{\lwidth}{2002 -- 2007}
& \textbf{Education 2 (University 2)}%
% @shouldshowgrades should be true here
\\[0.5em]

% \end{education}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide what the expected output is.

Comment: @PeterGrill - added LaTeX code that would produce identical expected output

Comment: Follow up question: [Misalignment of table columns when using multirow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63711/misalignment-of-table-columns-when-using-multirow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following with `\usepackage[showgrades]{cvtools}` produces:

[image]

or with `\usepackage{cvtools}`:

[image]

### Changes:

- Added package option to `\usepackage[showgrades]{cvtools}` so that `showgrades` was enabled.
- Few spurious spaces eliminated by adding a `%` (noted in code).
- You were missing a `\` in:

  ```
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@shouldshowgrades}{1}}
  ```
- Changed `\def` to `\gdef` so that those settings are available when needed.
- Eliminated the `\multirow` for displaying the years.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{cvtools.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{cvtools}[2012/07/16 v1.0.0]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}           % for \ifstrempty, \ifdef
\RequirePackage{ifthen}             % for \ifthenelse
\RequirePackage{longtable}          % for tables that span more than one page
\RequirePackage{multirow}           % for table columns that span more than one row
\RequirePackage{tabularx}           % for simple column stretching
\RequirePackage{xcolor}             % for colours

%================================================%
% Declare options
%================================================%
\newif\if@showgrades

\DeclareOption{showgrades}{\@showgradestrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{cvtools}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}}

\ProcessOptions

%================================================%
% For table styling
%================================================%
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}%
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft}p{#1}}%
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{p{#1}}%
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}%
%------------------------------------------------%

%================================================%
% \begin{education}
% \educationItem{beginYear}{endYear}{name}{institution}{\educationGrade{subject}{grade} ...}
% \end{education}
%================================================%
\newenvironment{education}%
{%
\def\lwidth{0.16\textwidth}%
\def\rwidth{0.78\textwidth}%
%
\newcommand\educationGrade[2]{##1 & ##2\\}%
%
\newcommand\educationItem[5]{%
% Check if we should display tools
\if@showgrades%
    \ifstrempty{##5}%
        {% showGrades is true, but this \educationItem has no grades to display.
            \gdef\@numRows{1}%
            \gdef\@shouldshowgrades{0}% <-- added %
        }%
        {% showGrades is true and this \educationItem has grades to display.
            \gdef\@numRows{2}%
            \gdef\@shouldshowgrades{1}% <-- added %
        }%
\else%
    % showGrades is false.
    \gdef\@numRows{1}%
    \gdef\@shouldshowgrades{0}% <-- added %
\fi%
%
% Education period
%\multirow{\@numRows}{\lwidth}{##1 -- ##2}%
##1 -- ##2% <-- Eliminated \multirow 

%
% Name and institution
& \textbf{##3 (##4)}%
%
% Grades
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@shouldshowgrades}{1}}% <-- corrected (missing \)
    {%
        \\*%
        & \begin{tabularx}{\rwidth}{Xr}%
        ##5%
        \end{tabularx}%
    }%
    {}%
\\[0.5em]%
}%
%
\begin{longtable}{L{\lwidth}!{\VRule}R{\rwidth}}%
}%
{\end{longtable}}%
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage[showgrades]{cvtools}% <-- added package option
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}   % extend page margins

\begin{document}
\section*{Education}
\begin{education}
    \educationItem{2008}{2012}%
    {Education 1}%
    {University 1}%
    {}%
    %
    \educationItem{2002}{2007}%
    {Education 2}%
    {University 2}%
    {%
    \educationGrade{Subject 1}{90/100}%
    \educationGrade{Subject 2}{88/100}%
    \educationGrade{Subject 3}{97/100}%
    \educationGrade{Subject 4}{94/100}%
    \educationGrade{Subject 5}{95/100}%
    }
\end{education}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Peter. However, I would like to use the multirow there... the reason is that I do a similar thing in another environment with longer text in the left column. Without multirow the second row is shifted down to make room for the text in the upper left cell... hence why the multirow is required. Why is it that doing it your way (but using the multirow), the left and right columns become out of alignment?

Comment: @JoshuaSpence: I am not sure what is going on with the `\multirow`.  I would suggest posting a follow up question specifically for the `\multirow` issue, with this MWE as it is already packaged, and reference that that is a follow up to this question.